# Save and retrieve Photos with all their metadata locally on iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift4

I am currently taking photos from the users iPhone making them jpegs, then saving them using file Manager and then saving their paths with core data.

The way I do it I can’t show live images or later export the image with its previous meta data.

My question is what is the correct way to save an image locally with all its meta data and live status so it can be displayed and exported later but only inside the app. I don’t want the images to be viable outside the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Taking The image:**

Take a look at the `UIImagePickerController` class and use it to take pictures. Taking pictures with this, will NOT save the images automatically to the iOS gallery.

The mentioned `UIImagePickerController` will notify a delegate `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and call the function `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any])`.

From the second parameter, the info dictionary, you can request most of the images metadata, livePhoto and so on. The necessary keys can be found inside the extension of `UIImagePickerController` called `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey`.

For example, here is how I then retrieve the images coordinate if available:

```
if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
      let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageURL], options: nil)
      if let asset = result.firstObject, let location = asset.location {
          let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
          let lon = location.coordinate.longitude
          print("Here's the lat and lon \(lat) + \(lon)")
      }
}
```

**Saving the image onto the phone within your app?:**

I use `JSONEncoder`. You can use this class to encode and then decode your custom image class again.

Your custom image class, which has the UIImage and all the other properties must then implement the `Codable` protocol.
Afterwards, use the `JSONEncoder` to create `Data` of the object via its `encode()` method and save it to an app private location with the help of a `FileManager`.
Later on, you may read all files from that location again with the `FileManager`, `decode()` with the `JSONEncoder` and voila you have all your images again in the form of your custom image class.

**Saving the image to the users gallery "Exporting":**

Here's an example of how I again save that image to the users gallery as a way of exporting it:

```
private static func saveImageToGallery(picture: UIImage, lat: Double?, lon: Double?) {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                let request = PHAssetCreationRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: picture)
                if let _lat = lat, let _lon = lon {
                    request.location = CLLocation(latitude: _lat, longitude: _lon)
                }
            })
        }
```

I hope this will be enough to guide you to the correct way.

Comment: Yes that's how I retrieve them and then turn them into jpgs. How can I save the image with all its data ?  Can I save it as data with coreData?

I want to be able to save photos that are accessible only through the application.

Comment: You can make use of CoreData or just encode the object with `JSONEncoder`. In both cases, you must have a class which has the UIImage and all the attributes you want to store with that image.

Comment: hmmm okey and one last thing to make sure I understand....I Save all the properties with core data and the image as a png right? If I want to export how do I "re assemble" the PHAsset with all its meta Data and the image to the user gallery....

Comment: I will update my answer in a minute to answer you comment^^

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope there's everything you need to read on how to do it. Of course one could go into more detail, but this should equip you with enough ideas on how to do it.